# Where does rationality break in the Leibniz formula for π?

Tags: sequences-and-series, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, pi

[Lebniz's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) is an infinite sum of fractions, meaning we are dealing with rational numbers everywhere in it. If you start to approximate π (π over 4) by calculating the partial sums of the formula, you can keep using fractions - it's all just the matter of finding the least common multiple of the denominators and thus expanding the fractions.

The approximation goes like 1, 2/3, 13/15, 76/105, ...

Theoretically, you can repeat this fraction expansion infinite number of times. And no matter how long you're doing it, you will always get a rational number.

But if you never stop, you do it all the way down to infinity, the result is π over 4, which is insanely irrational. What is the point where (and the reason why) this rational pattern breaks?

Comment: Any real number is a sum of a series of rationals (think of its decimal expansion). So why should $\pi/4$ be any different?

Comment: And why the downvote? Can someone explain why this is a stupid question?

Comment: It's not a bad question. The point is that all real numbers, rational and irrational, are constructed as limits of rational numbers. That is essentially how the real numbers are defined.

Comment: Notice how the denominators of the terms, and of their sum, grow without limit. Similarly, each partial product in the [Wallis product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product) formula is rational, but the limit isn't.

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120341/proof-that-pi-is-rational

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such point. This is an instance of the fact that *any* real number (rational or not) can be expressed as the limit of a sequence of rational numbers.

A similar situation occurs with the sequence $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. *Each* term of the seuence is greater than $0$. But the limit of the sequence is $0$. When do the terms of the sequence *become* $0$? Never!

Comment: So the Leibniz formula also will never become π over 4, it's just approximating it?

Comment: @mshthn A formula cannot become a number. What the formula asserts is that numbers of the form $1-\frac13+\frac15-\frac17+\cdots+\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$ are as close as you want to $\frac\pi4$ if $n$ is large enough.

Comment: Ok, I think now I understand the downvote on the question.

Answer (score 2):

It breaks nowhere, it is just that a sequence of rational numbers can converge to irrational numbers. You can ask the same question about the sequence 3, 3.1, 3.14, 3.141, 3.1415, etc.

Comment: You are basically saying the same thing but I saw the answer from @JoséCarlosSantos first and I can't accept two answers. Sorry about that and thanks!

Comment: It is &!@* slow to type answers on this Android phone ;) You're welcome.